# How to let proper arrow navigation on terminal app open by shortcut?

Tags: bash, terminal, manjaro, konsole

I'm trying to create a shortcut for a  terminal app called "Fricas".
By now I was able to create it with manjaro's app manager passing the following code line to open it:

```
konsole -e fricas
```

But when I do so, for some reason konsole stops from properly handling arrows and other commands like ctrl+C, and all I get when trying to use them is their code like the "]]A^" things.
Is there a way of opening by a shortcut without messing this up?

I have already tried with

```
bash -c "fricas"
```

either but with no success

Comment: If it is emitting control sequences, the terminal emulator _is_ properly handling arrows, because that is all that is the responsibility of that software.  Handling of these control sequences as input is not the task of the terminal emulator.

Comment: but when I open it manually, by calling it in the terminal, it behaves differently, I can navigate using the arrows. I want to know why it stops behaving like that and waht should I do to make it behave like this